# Magnolia 5.5.7 Stories App Internalization

Tags: magnolia

We want to use the Stories App instead of Pages.
How is internalization handled in the stories? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, It is not supported. However, you could use the existing patterns to implement it yourself (if you are motivated to).

I can say that we are interested in the topic though and most likely there will be some activity about the topic at some point.